# PHP foreach and while loop to order timeslots

Tags: php, mysql, html, loops, foreach

After a little help here.
I'm looking to produce some code that will take an incoming array of data, and order the data by time (This I can do easily enough)

There is 22 blocks of time in my table so I need each row to equate to 22 (Each item in the array has a block value) this I can do

What I am after is taking that array of data and say if a piece of data is 3 slots from 09:00am it takes 3 slots (I can do) but if 09:00am is the first item for that day i need the loop to first create 1 block slots until it finds the first slot in the array, then if the next slot set is at 14:00 it fills in the slots in between

i.e. Instead of

```
test1, 2slots, 09:00, room1
test1, 1slot, 12:00, room1 
test1, 2slots, 13:00, room1
test1, 4slots, 15:00, room1
10
11
12
13
...
22
```

I would like

```
1
2
3
4
test1, 2slots, 09:00, room1, 6
7
8
9
10
test1, 1slot, 12:00, room1, 11
12
test1, 2slots, 13:00, room1, 14
15
16
test1, 4slots, 15:00, room1, 20
21
22
```

my function is currently (This returns the first block)

```
if(is_array($meetrooms)){
$i = 0;
foreach($meetrooms as $valuer){ 
    $b = $valuer['num_blocks'];
    $i += $b;
    ?>
    <span><?php echo $valuer['title'] . " " . $valuer['num_blocks'] . " " . $valuer['room_name']  . " " . $i . " " . br() ;?></span>
<?php       
}
if($i != 22){ 
    while($i <= 22){ ?>
        <span><?php echo $i . br() ;?></span>
<?php
        $i++;
    }
}
}
```

My array is reduced but structured as

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [mr_id] => 3
        [title] => test1 meeting
        [description] => Some meeting going on here
        [staff_id] => 2454
        [room_name] => room1
        [start_date] => 2012-04-20 00:43:58
        [start_time] => 08:00:00
        [end_date] => 2012-04-20 00:43:58
        [end_time] => 09:00:00
        [num_blocks] => 2
    )
```

Any help would be fantastic!!!
Need anything else please ask

**EDIT**:

I'm 90% the way there now

Only problem is It's concatenating the value outside the while loop to the while loop . . . ???

```
if(is_array($meetingrooms))
{
$time = date('H:i', strtotime("07:00"));
$i = 1;
foreach($meetingrooms as $valuer)
{ 
    while ($time < $valuer['start_time'])
    { ?>
        <span><?php echo "....." . $time . " " . $i . ".....";?></span>
    <?php
        $prev = date('H:i', strtotime($time));
        $next = strtotime('+30mins', strtotime($prev));
        $time = date('H:i', $next);
        $i++;
    }
    $nummins = $valuer['num_blocks'] * 30 - 30;
    $next = strtotime('+' . $nummins . 'mins', strtotime($time));
    $time = date('H:i', $next);
    $b = $valuer['num_blocks'];
    echo  "td" . $valuer['num_blocks'];
    $i = $i + 1;
}
$timetofinish = date('H:i', strtotime("18:00"));
if ($time < $timetofinish)
{
    while ($time < $timetofinish)
    {
        echo "<span>......$time..." . $i  . "</span>";
        $prev = date('H:i', strtotime($time));
        $next = strtotime('+30mins', strtotime($prev));
        $time = date('H:i', $next); 
        $i++;
    }
}
}
```

What it now returns is

```
.....07:00 1..... .....07:30 2..... .....08:00 3..... td2    .....09:00 5..... .....09:30 6..... .....10:00 7..... .....10:30 8..... td1     .....11:00 10..... .....11:30 11..... .....12:00 12..... td4    .....14:00 14..... .....14:30 15..... .....15:00 16..... td1......15:30...18......16:00...19......16:30...20......17:00...21......17:30...22
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create some sort of a classroom reservation time-table?

```
date_default_timezone_set ( 'GMT' );
$meetingrooms = array ( /* ... YOUR DATA ... */ );

define ('MAX_SLOTS', 22);
define ('START_TIME', strtotime('05:00'));
define ('END_TIME', strtotime('22:00'));
$rooms = array ( "room1", "room2" );
$reserved = array();
foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    $reserved[$room] = array();
    for($t = START_TIME; $t <= END_TIME; $t = strtotime('+30mins', $t)) {
        $reserved[$room][$t] = "FREE";
    }
}

foreach ($meetingrooms as $valuer) {
   $t = strtotime($valuer['start_time']);
   while ( $t < strtotime($valuer['end_time'])) {
       $reserved[$valuer['room_name']][$t] = $valuer;
       $t += strtotime('+30mins', $t);
   }      
}

foreach ($reserved as $roomname=>$reservations) {
    echo "{$roomname}: ";
    foreach ($reservations as $t=>$valuer) {
        echo date("H:i", $t).( ($valuer === "FREE") ? "...." : $valuer['title'])." | ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Now you can modify the output (add HTML/XML/whatever) to suit your requirements.

Comment: It's a meeting room booking facility.
Just trying to improve the functionality

It'll be a row of slots each block representing 1/2 an hour. So if a meeting is 3 1/2hrs it'll take 7 blocks

Comment: I'd suggest a different approach then. First - render the diagram, THEN iterate over your 'events' and put them in the table.

Comment: That purely returns the events after it has printed out the whole day first

    Room1: 07:00.... | 07:30.... | 08:00.... | 08:30.... | 09:00.... | 09:30.... | 10:00.... | 10:30.... | 11:00.... | 11:30.... | 12:00.... | 12:30.... | 13:00.... | 13:30.... | 14:00.... | 14:30.... | 15:00.... | 15:30.... | 16:00.... | 16:30.... | 17:00.... | 17:30.... | 18:00.... | 08:00test1 | 13:00test3 | 16:00test4 | 17:00test2

Comment: Thanks for the help so far though

Comment: OK. I've now got the events falling into the right place in the chain. i.e. a 8am event falls at 8am.
BUT
The

    $t += strtotime('+30mins', $t);

doesn't seem to be working. If you echo out the time after each pass through here, it is incorrect. As well as such. it continues to write the next time in the chain. IN this case 08:30 rather than say 10:30
This is either because a) We've firstly written the schedule out or b) the incorrect adding of time has caused it to ignore the creation of the next one in the right place

Comment: if you could make some of your data available, I could give you a more precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code.

```
    <?php 
        //Sample time loop.
        $time = new DateTime('2011-11-17 08:00:00');
        $end = new DateTime('2011-11-17 20:00:00');

        while ($time < $end) {

            echo $stamp = $time->format('h:i a') . '</br>';
            $time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 30 . 'M'));
        }
    ?>
```

Resource: [PHP foreach and while loop to order timeslots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245131/php-foreach-and-while-loop-to-order-timeslots/22039293#22039293)